# PropertyGrid collection display text

Tags: c#, collections, propertygrid

In C#, when using a `PropertyGrid` where an object has a `Collection`, what determines if the value next to the `DisplayName` shows the value of `"(Collection)"`?

Is there a specific attribute for this value?

Thanks

Comment: It seems `(Collection)` appears on a `List<T>` and not on `IEnumerable<T>`. A fixed array has an expandable node which is quite different from a collection.

Answer (score 4):

You can use TypeConverters.

```
public class MyCollectionTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (value is List<string>)
        {
            return string.Join(",", ((List<string>) value).Select(x => x));
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

and add as attribute;

```
    [TypeConverter(typeof(MyCollectionTypeConverter))]
    public List<string> Prop1 { get; set; }
```

Ref: [How to: Implement a Type Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ayybcxe5.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Kaya's answer didn't work for me - but - I found when you have any type converter, the property grid will show base.ToString() instead of (Collection), we can use that.

```
public class CollectionToStringOverrideConverter : TypeConverter
{
}
[TypeConverter(typeof(CollectionToStringOverrideConverter))]
public class FormattedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (this?.Count > 0)
            return string.Join("|", this);
        return "No items in collection";
    }
}
```

The FormattedList class now has a type converter, so the default ToString() is used, and we can put whatever we want there. Just define your property as a FormattedList instead of a List and you're set.